# Bucle en Angular : Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, bucles

les pido por favor ayuda con este error que segun los tutores donde estoy realizando el curso no lo puedo ver en el navegador por un bucle, pero no se la verdad como poder solucionarlo o donde esta el mismo, paso imagen de la terminal y codigo de los dos archivos que estan en el proyecto al cual me dirigen;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
uno es el main.ts
´´´

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.catch(err => console.error(err));
´´´
```

y el otro es el index.js (esto no es codigo en el proyecto)

```
´´´
"use strict";
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Google LLC All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.AngularWebpackLoaderPath = exports.AngularWebpackPlugin = exports.default = void 0;
var loader_1 = require("./loader");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "default", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return loader_1.angularWebpackLoader; } });
var plugin_1 = require("./plugin");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "AngularWebpackPlugin", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return plugin_1.AngularWebpackPlugin; } });
exports.AngularWebpackLoaderPath = __filename;
´´´
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" en Angular generalmente significa que se ha producido un bucle infinito o una recursión infinita en tu código. Esto ocurre cuando una función o método se llama a sí mismo repetidamente sin una condición de salida adecuada.

Este error puede ocurrir por varias razones, como:

1. Una función o método que se llama a sí mismo directamente sin una condición de salida.
2. Una llamada recursiva que no termina debido a una condición incorrecta.
3. Un bucle infinito que causa que una función se llame a sí misma repetidamente.

Comment: Está bien que aclares cuando se produce ese error, pero OP pregunta específicamente porqué se produce en su código. ¿Cuál de esas razones que expones es la que está generando el error y en que parte de su código se da?

Comment: Gracias por responderme, te consulto si hay alguna forma de saber donde esta mi error, o tengo que revisar todas y cada una de las funciones? Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Tendría que revisar mas a fondo. en las imágenes que muestras no hay claridad de una recursividad o bucle infinito. El index js no existe error. 
revisa tus importaciones en los módulos. 
Llamadas a funciones. 
o bucles infinitos. Saludos .